# Enable stored procedures after database downgrade

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I've recently upgraded/downgraded a database as stated on this link:

https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21351101

Specifically, it was from db2 9.7.5 (32bit) to 9.7.6 (64bit) to 9.7.0 (32bit)
(license issues, bear with me). Now, after successfully restoring my backup to 9.7.0, I can't run any stored procedures.

On resolving the problem, It says:

> Contact your DBAdmins and let them verify if the required stored
>   procedures are enabled on the DB2 database. The required stored
>   procedures are: JAVA Database Connectivity (JDBC) Open Database
>   Connectivity (ODBC)

Then I'm at a loss. How do I enable a procedure?

Comment: You may want to try `UPGRADE DATABASE` [as explained here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.qb.upgrade.doc/doc/t0007193.html)

Comment: It worked!. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After upgrading or downgrading your DB2 instance you need to also upgrade or downgrade all databases in that instance. You do that by running the `UPGRADE DATABASE` command, as [explained in the manual](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.qb.upgrade.doc/doc/t0007193.html), which will create catalog tables, views, and other system objects appropriate for the version and fix pack level.